# Dynamically set the height of a Button to be the height of a Textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is a little thing, but I can't find anything at all in regard on how to go about doing it!

In the picture below, there is a `textarea` with a styled (and disabled) `button`purely for aesthetic purposes:

[image]

But when you resize the `textarea`, this happens:

[image]

This doesn't look so great.

I want to tie the dynamic height of the `textarea` to the height of the `button` so that they stay together at whatever height, but I cant find anything like this.

How do you tie an elements styling to another's?

**Note** - Much more confident at PHP than jQuery/javascript, but obviously won't refuse answers in those languages.

Comment: put both in a outer container with float left(for textarea) and and give height equal to both .container height will be auto. I am not a designer but i will do in this way

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either disable the resise of textarea using the following :

---

```
textarea {
    resize: none;
}
```

---

or use this fiddle(I did not create it) by making necessary changes.

---

http://jsfiddle.net/gbouthenot/D2bZd/

---

Comment: Awesome. Happy to help.

Comment: That's a lot of unnecessary JS for something that' easily achievable with CSS. Also, there's a lot of flickering on the element that is being resized by the JS.

Comment: Agreed. I wasn't aware of the CSS solution earlier. Now I am.

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox can do that

```css
div {
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 1em;
}
textarea,
botton {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <textarea id="output">My size will be matched by the button</textarea>
  <button>Click</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way would be to wrap the textarea within another element and set the `display` property of that parent to `flex`, like so:

```css
div{
  display:flex;
}
textarea{
  resize:vertical;
}
```

```html
<div>
<textarea></textarea>
<button>text</button>
</div>
```

Depending on your requirements and other styles, you may need to adjust some of the other [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) properties. See [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) as well for details on browser support and prefixing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do it with HTML and CSS, no javascript or php code needed:

```
<div class="container">
<textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
<button type="button">Click Me!</button>
</div>

.container{
  overflow: auto;
  position: relative;
}

textarea, button{
  float: left;
}

button{
  position:absolute;
  height:100%;
  width:150px;
}
```

Here is a JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/83uuk6gx/1/

EDIT:

You can remove the min-height, it will work without it (I removed it from code above and updated jsfiddle).  Also I would not use flex as it will impose restrictions on earlier version of the browsers.  IE9 does not support it I believe, here is more details on it: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex.asp

Comment: See this is what I had but it breaks the styling up in a way that I couldn't fix. Good answer, and in most cases the correct one so I'll upvote it, but the ticked one shall remain ticked as its specific to me - Just a note for others.